# MySQL 5.7 index_merge_intersection bug

Tags: php, mysql, subquery, exists

I've uncovered what appears to be a bug in MySQL

http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=79675

Explanation and workaround:

I have an EXISTS subquery which returns different results on the same data in different MySQL versions.

Example query: Select PCR #100 and ensure one of the crew members has a `user_id` = 10

```
SELECT * 
FROM pcrs
WHERE id = 100
AND EXISTS (
    SELECT NULL FROM pcrs p
        LEFT OUTER JOIN crews ON crews.pcr_id = p.id
        WHERE crews.user_id = 10
        AND p.id = pcrs.id
)
```

In MySQL 5.5, the query works properly and a single row (`id` = 100) is returned.

In MySQL 5.7 the same query incorrectly returns no results.

Interestingly, If I change the outer `WHERE` from

`WHERE id = 100`

to

`WHERE id BETWEEN 100 and 101`

Then MySQL 5.7 correctly returns a single row (`id` = 100)

When matching a specific row id in the outer query, the EXISTS subquery always fails (on 5.7, possibly 5.6 as well)

This issue is caused/effected by the MySQL optimizer switch: `index_merge_intersection`.

If I change this setting to OFF:

`SET optimizer_switch="index_merge_intersection=off";`

the query works as expected in 5.7

Comment: What happens if you change `SELECT NULL` to `SELECT 1`?

Comment: Why are you using `LEFT OUTER JOIN` in the subquery? The `WHERE crews.user_id` condition will filter out any non-matching rows, so it's equivalent to an `INNER JOIN`.

Comment: Is the `id` column defined to be integer type (INT) or some other datatype? What seems really unusual to me is the reference to `pcrs` table in the FROM clause of the subquery. That isn't needed. The check you describe can be achieved with **`EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM crews WHERE crews.pcr_id = pcrs.id AND crews.user_id = 10)`**, without another reference to the pcrs table. (That doesn't explain the behavior you are observing.)

Comment: @Barmar no change on the SELECT  1 vs. null

Comment: @spencer7593 The reason for the additional reference is that the SQL statement is auto-generated and must support checking EXISTS on its own regardless of the outer query

Comment: It sounds like a bug in the query optimizer. Not much we can do here. Have you searched the MySQL bug list?